# AJAX request to PHP - Handling response data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Im working on some AJAX login function, making a request via PHP.
I am wondering how do I return data via the PHP so that I can handle it like the code mentioned below. I only worked on the javascript side and not the PHP server side so I am confused now.

I want to get a value/values stored in the response like data.name , data.sessionID , data.listOfnames

Is the data a JSON Object by itself?
Thanks!

The code below was used before and has been verified to work.

```js
function retrieveVersion(){
    var URL = RSlink + "/updates";
    $.ajax({
     headers : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "sessionid" : result
     },
     type : "GET",
     url : vURL,

     statusCode : {
      0 : function() {
       hideLoadingMsg();
       showError(networkError, false);
      },
      200 : function(data) {
       currentVersion = String(data.version);
       updatesArray=data.updates;
       });
       
       }
      }
     });​
```

Comment: You should show the PHP code you've tried..?

Comment: Do you have an example of the data returned by the PHP?

Comment: Also set PHP header of output to application/json, so Ajax functions can read it easily: header('Content-Type:application/json;');

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a php file for handling ajax calls. It should be available by this url - vURL.

In this file you need to create an array.

Something like this:

```
$data = array('data' => array('version' => yourversion, 'updates' => yourupdates));
```

Then you need to convert this object into json string. You can do this using json_encode() function

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

One thing to keep in mind: You need to echo your data and only. If somewhere in your file you will have some other echo-es, the result string returning to your ajax-funtion might be broken.